# Georeferencing reversal of image

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing

I georeferenced a map and it posted to canvas as a mirror image of the original map. I set my project CRS before starting and also made sure to set the same SRS for the Geotiff being created and saved. I made sure that my Eastings and Northings are correct.

[image: Mirror imaged georeferenced map]

Please see that Texas is on the wrong side of Louisiana, all text from the map is mirror imaged from the original way the map was georeferenced. North is still pointing north. I am using Version 2.82 and I entered the latitude longitude values in dd mm ss.ss

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

---

I re-attempted the georeference by adding points in clockwise motion, starting with top right corner. Output shows that georeferenced points & the map itself are mirror imaged. CRS is NAD27 Louisiana South EPSG: 26782. Transform type: Thin Plate Spline, Resample method: Near neighbor, Compress: None

[image: Georeferenced map showing mirror imaged map with points also mirror imaged]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Would you be able to **edit** your question to provide more details like the GIS software and version that you are using, please?

Comment: Is it a mirror image up/down (north-south) or left/right?

Comment: Did you reference by clicking sample points on another map, or did you enter the coordinates manually?

Comment: What software are you using? What steps did you take, in detail?

Comment: please add information to your original question (not in comments) about the crs you used, false e/n, and the other questions in comments which will hopefully help us help you.

Comment: did you go anti-clockwise as you georeferenced? clockwise would be the prescribed method.

Comment: Are you using negative longitude values or not? I can't zoom in enough to tell. It looks like you have the values swapped because they should be negative. And that's going to georeference to lat/lon, not to the state plane zone.

Comment: @mkennedy That's a great guess.  The coordinates shown on the images are all near x:93 and y:30, whereas correct lon-lat for this region of the earth are near (-93, 30).  BTW Brad, the order in which links are created in georeferencing is irrelevant: any order is perfectly fine and leads to exactly the same solutions (at least up to tiny double precision floating point error).